# proof of equivalent statements for an element of a ring belonging to every maximal left ideal of that ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, ideals

I would like to see a proof of the following.

Let $R$ be a ring and let $a\in R$. Prove that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $a$ belongs to every maximal left ideal of $R$.
2. $1+ra$ has  left inverse for every $r\in R$.
3. $1+ra$ is invertible for every $r\in R$.

I have been searching for it in order to compare it to my own proof. Does anyone know where I can find a proof or does anyone know how to prove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

J.Lambek, *Lectures on Rings and Modules*, 1966, Chapt. 2, Prop. 7.